# Designing a circuit for a single DC-DC converter to power multiple devices

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, dc-dc-converter

I need to power multiple devices from a single [RSDW40F-05](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/260/Meanwell_RSDW40_2cRDDW40-1855615.pdf) DC-DC converter: 3 microcontrollers (2 A each) and 2 case fans (50 mA each). The converter is rated for 8 A output. The data sheet recommends a few decoupling capacitors on the input/output. My main question is should I add more capacitors to the output considering multiple devices will share the converter output? Moreover, are there any other passive components that should be added to increase the reliability and noise characteristics of this circuit? I've included the recommended circuit from the datasheet and my current design.
[image: Recommended circuit]

[image: My circuit]

Comment: What happened to L1?

Answer (score 1):

The components on the schematic from the converter's datasheet are there to hit EMC targets.  Your decoupling capacitors should be located as close to the components they serve as possible, especially if they are going to be powered through wires coming off of the converter's board, which it looks like you're planning on.  The maximum output capacitance of the DC/DC converter is 20000 uF so I don't think you'll run into a problem there, but for most applications, an electrolytic bulk capacitor should be backed up by a smaller ceramic capacitor in the ~100nF range.

Comment: So, ignoring the EMC components, the multiple output caps could be replaced by a single electrolytic capacitor along with a ceramic? And yes, I plan or using 6 inch ribbon cable to power the devices.

Comment: You would need at least a small ceramic capacitor and probably an electrolytic at each of the powered devices.  The 6" of ribbon cable will introduce a non-trivial amount of inductance into the supply line and the capacitor close to the point of load ensures that the supply voltage remains at acceptable levels during and after abrupt changes in load current.